# In IE11 only, opacity after fading to 100%, for some reason goes back down to ~50%

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

The opacity fade works perfect in all browsers except IE11 and I can't figure out.

I don't even know how to describe it. It only happens after I fade in a child element and a parent element at the same time. But after that it screws up everything.

However when I try to replicate it as a simple test case it works fine in IE11 - https://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/9q6Lxc46/2/

Here is screencast showing the bug (not seen in the fiddle) - https://youtu.be/knFQ4UvZP0I

Here is jsfiddle pasted here:

```js
var FADE_ENTER_MS = 1000;
var FADE_LEAVE_MS = 1000;

var LOAD_MS = 5000;

function wait(ms, cb) {
    setTimeout(cb, ms);
}

function doEnter(el, parent) {
    parent.appendChild(el);
    el.classList.add('fade-enter');
    window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('height'); // force paint as element was just added, so opacity:0 needs to register
    wait(FADE_LEAVE_MS, function() { // wait for previous page to fade out
        el.classList.add('fade-enter-active');
        wait(FADE_ENTER_MS, function() {
            el.classList.remove('fade-enter');
            el.classList.remove('fade-enter-active');
        });
    });
}

function doLeave(el) {
    el.classList.add('fade-leave');
    window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('height'); // force paint
    el.classList.add('fade-leave-active');
    wait(FADE_LEAVE_MS, function() {
        // no need to mess with classList as i am removing element on line below
        // el.classList.remove('fade-leave');
        // el.classList.remove('fade-enter-active');
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
}

window.showPage = function(pageNum) {
    var leavingPageNum = pageNum === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    var leavingPage = document.querySelector('.page-' + leavingPageNum);
    var container = document.getElementById('page_fader');

    var page = document.createElement('div');
    page.setAttribute('class', 'page-' + pageNum + ' content-fader');


    var loading = document.createElement('div');
    loading.textContent = 'loading page ' + pageNum + '...';

    var content = document.createElement('div');
    content.innerHTML = 'CONTENT page ' + pageNum + ' <button onClick="showPage(' + leavingPageNum + ')">Show Page ' + leavingPageNum + '</button>';

    doLeave(leavingPage);
    doEnter(page, container);
    doEnter(loading, page);

    wait(LOAD_MS, function() {
        doLeave(loading);
        doEnter(content, page);
    });
}
```

```css
#page_fader > div { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; }

.content-fader > div { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:lightsteelblue; }

.fade-enter { opacity:0; }
.fade-enter.fade-enter-active { opacity:1; transition:opacity 1000ms; }
.fade-leave { opacity:1; }
.fade-leave.fade-leave-active { opacity:0; transition:opacity 1000ms; }
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="page_fader">
    <div class="content-fader page-1">
      <div class="content-content">CONTENT page 1 <button onClick="showPage(2)">Show Page 2</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my worst question ever. I tried to formulate a question for months. I don't even know how to ask other then to show it. May you please see it in action: at https://mlink.info

Here is my best attempt at a description:
Please click on "login" then "signup" then the "MLINK" logo. You see the opacity fades perfectly in and out to 100%. However after hitting search, it fades in a inner loading thing, then out when the content loads. Then the content loads to 100% opacity but for some god forsaken reason, it goes down to like 50%'ish, I have no no idea why.

Right clicking and doing "inspect element" makes the opacity 100% again O_O so weird.

I held off on this question for months, I just cannot figure it out. :( Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Selecting a DOM element in the debugging tools should cause the element to be prominently displayed. That's just the debugger. It's normal.

Comment: What happens if you drop the _force paint_ line and the rest of the code into a `setTimeout`? ... it will give the same effect as the _force redraw_ but IE11 might like that better

Comment: @LGSon - no effect, i cant reproduce the bug in test case :(

Comment: @ScottMarcus - clicking any other element is not changing the display attributes of anything else. :(

Comment: Well, I meant if you change it in your live site to see if it made any difference.

Comment: Ah thanks @LGSon I will try. I am using react and a plugin, so I will dig into that plugin and see if i can modify it. Thank you sir.